# Stein-haff shrinkage formula in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have a data matrix **X** of size **p*n** where **p=10** and **n=30**.

Assume the covariance matrix **S = XX'/n** and its eigenvalues by the vector **l**.

I want to compute this formula in MATLAB:

[image]

I began by writing the code but I don't know how to write the sum and especially for j different to i.

```
clear all;
close all;
clc

p=10;
n=30;
X=rand(p,n);
S=(X*X')/n;
l=eig(S);
```

Any help will be very appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is to iterate through your values in a `for` loop adding them to an accumulator variable. The twist in this case - excluding the entries where `i==j` - would be to use an `if` statement.

```
innersum = 0; % initialise it first
for j = 1:p
    if i ~= j % matlab''s way of saying 'not equal to'
        innersum = innersum + 1/(l(i)-l(j));
    end
end
```

That only takes care of the big sigma term. You would need to involve the other `n`, `p` and `l` terms as normal.

It looks like you'll need to produce an output for each value of `i` so again you will need to iterate through the `i`s in a loop, possibly storing the results in an array

```
for i = 1:p
    % do the big sum
    results(i) = output_of_quoted_equation;
end
```

Note that there are many other ways of doing this, most of them involving a programming concept called 'vectorisation'. If you're not familiar with it then don't worry about it, but as it's one of Matlab's major features you'll come across it a lot, and likely be given lots of answers that use it. It's conceptually more difficult than for loops, both to learn and to read, but it's widely used because it's usually much faster for massive datasets, and it's generally part of the 'Matlab way of doing things', such as there is one. However for small and even medium datasets the performance advantage is marginal.

Note also that both `i` and `j` have special meanings in Matlab (both are shortcuts to the imaginary unit, sqrt(-1)) and although it's convenient to use them as variable names it may break other things. `ii` and `jj` are good substitutes.

Comment: But I think you must write if "j ~=i" instead of " if i ~=j". Right ? :)

Comment: I can see that - we're inside the `j` loop so that should be the leading operand : ) I clearly suffer from an excessive need to alphabetise things...